# VsCode doesn't recognize modules (I'm using python 3.10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module

As the title says, apparently VsCode doesn't recognize several modules that I already installed on my MacBook. For example,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import request
from tkinter import *
```

And the error message says,

```
No module named 'bs4'
File "/Users/my_name/Desktop/VsCode Projects/weather_detecter/main.py", line 7, in 
<module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also, it says the same thing on requests, but not on tkinter. I tried sudo pip, -m, pip3 on both terminal.app and VsCode terminal, but the outcome is still the same. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

- You might need to select the correct python interpreter version first and then try importing the modules.
- OR, open terminal in VS Code and try reinstalling the modules with the command `python3 -m pip install <module_name>`

Comment: I changed the interpreter from .10 to .8.8 and it worked!! Thank you so much for your advice sir/ms!!